# How to securely provide a $_POST var in WP_Query with PHP 7?

Tags: php, wp-query, mysql

In PHP 5.5 you had the function

`mysql_real_escape_string()`

and I always did

`htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['...]));`

to secure against SQL-Injection.

With PHP 7 mysql_real_escape_string() is gone. An alternative is

`mysqli_real_escape_string()`

but that function needs a link to the mysqli object. When using WordPress to perform a query like this:

`$query_args = array( 's' => $_POST['search'] );
$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );`

I can't provide a mysqli object. So Do I have to leave all the security stuff to WordPress? Is it enough to do:

`$query_args = array( 's' => htmlspecialchars( $_POST['search'] ) );
$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );`

?

Comment: your code didn't add any security, no point in trying to maintain it.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Wordpress API does proper escaping, all you have done is to "break" the actual data that needed to be acted upon

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the answer to my question is that I can do:

`$query_args = array( 's' => $_POST['search'] );
$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );`

Comment: yes, wp_query will do whatever is the needed sanitization to access the DB. To display you might need to do some escaping

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try this, to sanitize the whole `$_POST` array

```
$_POST  = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Or to sanitize just a field, you could use the native WP function

```
$sanitized = sanitize_text_field ( $_POST['key'] );
```

Comment: Thx 4 your answer but seems its not necessary

Comment: Why "seems" ? any reference? regards

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

See full source code.